# Wordpress Ajax Always returning 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to fetch more posts on click via ajax.  In my functions I have localised the script

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'news', get_template_directory_uri().'/news/js/news.js', '', '', true );

//Localise script for ajax call
wp_localize_script( 'news', 'ajax_posts', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'noposts' => 'No Older Posts Found',
));
```

My Function for querying posts

```
function more_post_ajax(){

    $ppp = (isset($_POST["ppp"])) ? $_POST["ppp"] : 2;
    $page = (isset($_POST['pageNumber'])) ? $_POST['pageNumber'] : 0;


    header("Content-Type: text/html");

    $args = array(
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
        'paged'    => $page
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    $out = '';

    if ($loop -> have_posts()) :  while ($loop -> have_posts()) : $loop -> the_post();
        $out .='<article class="post-container clearfix">
                    <div class="post-inner clearfix">

                    <div class="post-image">
                        '.get_the_post_thumbnail().'
                    </div>
                    <h1>'.the_title().'</h1>
                    <span class="date">Date: '.get_the_date().'</span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="author">Author: '.the_author().'</span>
                    <br>
                    '.get_custom_excerpt(get_the_content()).'
                    <a class="read-more" href="'.get_the_permalink().'" title="Read More"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/news/img/read-more.png" alt="Read More"></a>
                    </div>
                </article>';
    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    echo $out;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
```

and then my jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var ppp = 2; // Post per page
    var pageNumber = 1;


    function load_posts(){
        pageNumber++;
        var str = '&pageNumber=' + pageNumber + '&ppp=' + ppp + '&action=more_post_ajax';
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            url: ajax_posts.ajaxurl,
            data: str,
            success: function(data){

                console.log(data);

                var $data = jQuery(data);
                if($data.length){
                    jQuery(".posts-wrapper").append($data);
                    jQuery(".load-more").attr("disabled",false);
                } else{
                    jQuery(".load-more").attr("disabled",true);
                }
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
            }

        });
        return false;
    }

    jQuery(".load-more").on("click",function(e){ // When btn is pressed.

        jQuery(".load-more").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
        load_posts();

        e.preventDefault();

    });

});
```

The ajax response is always 0.  Could anyone help please.

Comment: And what should it be?

Comment: `die($page)` looks to me like killing the request from the top. Is that for debugging? You could verify the whole request with `wp_die( var_dump( $_REQUEST ) )` to make sure..

Comment: Yeah sorry that was added when I was trying to figure out if it was ever reaching the ajax_posts function.  When I check in network the the ajax request is successful and it's hitting the success callback of the ajax call but it looks like for some reason the code in ajax_posts is not returning the next 2 posts as expected.

Comment: It should be the next 2 posts

Comment: I found that this error usually happens when you don't set the action. That doesn't seem to be your case, but could it be the way your data string is setup? Have you tried passing it as an object literal `{ pageNumber:  pageNumber, ppp: ppp, action: more_post_ajax }`?

Comment: This tells me that more_post_ajax is not defined which is because I have localised the script.

Answer (score 2):

Try die() function in the end of PHP function. It will helps.

UPD: I`ve made some simple version of your problem code to check it and it works. I think it will helps you.
You are able to change inner PHP script to your logic and it won`t returns 0.

PHP:

```
function more_post_ajax(){
  echo "Hello";
  die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');

function custom_scripts_init(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/custom.js', array('jquery') );
  wp_localize_script( 'custom', 'ajaxPosts', array(
    'customUrl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'noposts' => 'No Older Posts Found',
));

}
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_scripts_init');
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#page").append("<button type='button' class='load-more'/>");
var ppp = 2; // Post per page
var pageNumber = 1;


function load_posts(){
    pageNumber++;
    var str = '&pageNumber=' + pageNumber + '&ppp=' + ppp + '&action=more_post_ajax';
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: ajaxPosts.customUrl,
        data: str,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //$loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
        }

    });
    return false;
}

jQuery(".load-more").on("click",function(e){ // When btn is pressed.

   // jQuery(".load-more").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
    load_posts();

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

});

Comment: Using wp_die() is even better !

Comment: Tried all of these.  It's going to be something really easy I'm sure of it but it is driving me nuts.

Comment: Have you tried to print your WP_Query object?

Comment: I don't think it's hitting the function more_post_ajax for whatever reason.

Comment: if I add die($_POST['ppp']); right at the top of the function more_post_ajax then it shoud definitely return that variable but it isn't

Comment: I think there is an error in your Ajax query.  Could you try to write some test function in PHP that returns some "Hello World" string to your page?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes to this, I just thought I would add what the issue was.

I inherited the job from another developer and for reasons I will never understand there was ob_start at the top of the functions file.  This was causing the ajax request to fail.

Thanks